# Как создать фильтрацию товаров?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Я хочу реализовать фильтрацию как [здесь](https://www.ozon.ru/highlight/65179/?category=7500&price=5937.000%3B17599.000&sorting=new), то есть с помощью REST по интернет-адресу.
Меня интересует механизмы реализации в Django такой фильтрации. Если можно лучше скинуть ссылку на какие-то интернет-ресурсы.

Comment: Да легко. Вот, как и просили, ссылка на какой-то интернет ресурс: https://www.google.com/

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/